# Make some content changeable with one click using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am a newbie developer and started to use Laravel to code.

My problem is that, I can't make this content changeable with the menu click.
I am really confused about how to use Ajax in this condition.

My routes.php:

```
Route::get('articles',array('as'=>'articles','uses'=>'articles@index'));
Route::get('author/(:any)', array('as'=>'article','uses'=>'articles@view'));
Route::get('abouts',array('as'=>'abouts','uses'=>'abouts@index'));
```

My default.blade.php(shortly included with the scripts)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
    <title>{{$title}}</title>
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/ajax.js') }}
    .......
  </head>
    <body>
    ........
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page">
               {{ $content }}
    </div>
    <!-- SIDEBAR -->
    <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar-content">

     <ul id="menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="<?php echo URL::to_route('articles'); ?>">ANASAYFA</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo URL::to_route('abouts'); ?>">HAKKIMIZDA</a></li>
 .......
   <script type="text/javascript">var BASE = "<?php echo URL::base(); ?>";</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My views are inside div/#content.

My ajax.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebar-content ul li a').click(function(e) {
        // prevent the links default action
        // from firing
        e.preventDefault();
        // attempt to GET the new content
        $.get(BASE +'#content', function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            console.log(data);

        });
    })
});
```

My articles controller:

```
<?php

class Articles_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true; 
    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function get_index(){
             $this->layout->title = "Anasayfa";
             $this->layout->content = View::make('articles.index')
             ->with('articles',Article::order_by('id')->get());
         }

        public function get_view($id){
            $this->layout->title = "Hizmetlerimiz";
          $this->layout->content = View::make('articles.view')
            ->with('article',Article::find($id));
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace the content of `<div id="page">`.

I think you should write `$('#page').html(data);`

Comment: hello , I made as you said. I get all my javascripts reloaded. When I check console.log(data.) I can see , It gets all the source code of the page. I cant get what is wrong?

Comment: Your first argument to `$.get` is the URL that you get back from the Ajax request. `BASE+'#content'` seems wrong (in Firebug you can see exactly which URL you try to get). You want to get the page from the href. Try to replace `BASE+'#content'` with `$(this).attr('href')`.